# C# pointers on pointers

Tags: c#, pointers

I have never used pointers before and now I need to and even though I've read up on them I still have no clue on how to use them!
I am using a third party product (Mitov Signal Lab)and I am using a control that has an event that will allow me to intercept the data. When I enter the event I have access to "args" and one of the statements will return a pointer.  Now this points to a buffer of 4096 double values (one a real number and the next an imaginiary number etc).  So this is the code:

```
 private void genericComplex1_ProcessData(object Sender, Mitov.SignalLab.ProcessComplexNotifyArgs Args)
    {
        unsafe
        {
         IntPtr pointer =  Args.InBuffer.Read(); 

         // now what????  I want to get each double value, do some calculations on them
         // and return them to the buffer.
         }
      args.sendOutPutData = true;
   }
```

I'm assuming that i need to assign pointer to Args.InBuffer.Read()
But I've tried some examples I've seen and I just get errors.  I'm using visual studio 2010 and i'm compiling with the /unsafe.
Here's an update. There are additional methods such as Args.Inbuffer.Write(), and Args.Inbuffer.Modify()  but I still can't figure out how to access the individual components of the buffer.

Ok here are more details. I used the Marshall.copy.  Here is the code:

```
   private void genericComplex1_ProcessData(object Sender, Mitov.SignalLab.ProcessComplexNotifyArgs Args)
    {
        //used to generate a phase corrected Q signal
        //equations:
        // real = real
        // imaginary = (1 + amplitudeimbalance)(real*cos(phaseImbalance) + imaginary*sin(phaseImbalance)
        //but amplitude imbalance is already corrected therefore

        //imaginary = real * cos(phaseCorrection) + imaginary*sin(phaseCorrection)

        double real;
        double imaginary;
        double newImaginary;

        var bufferSize = Convert.ToInt32(Args.InBuffer.GetSize());

        Mitov.SignalLab.ComplexBuffer ComplexDataBuffer = new Mitov.SignalLab.ComplexBuffer(bufferSize);
        ComplexDataBuffer.Zero();

        IntPtr pointer = Args.InBuffer.Read();
        IntPtr pointer2 = ComplexDataBuffer.Write();

        var data = new double[8192];

        Marshal.Copy(pointer, data, 0, 8192);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i+=2)
        {
            data[i] = data[i];
            data[i + 1] = data[i] * Math.Cos(phaseCorrection) + data[i+1] * Math.Sin(phaseCorrection); 
        }

        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pointer2, 8192);

       Args.SendOutputData = false;
       genericComplex1.SendData(ComplexDataBuffer);

    }
```

Now, this does not work.  The reason is it takes too long.  I am sampling audio from a sound card at 192,000 samples a second. The event above fires each time there is a 4096 buffer available.  Thus every 20 milliseconds a new buffer arrives. This buffer is then sent to a fast fourier transform routine that produces a graph of signal strength vs frequency. The imaginary data is actually the same as the real data but it is phase shifted by 90 degrees.  This is how it is in a perfect world.  However the phase is never 90 degrees due to imbalances in the signal, different electronics paths, different code and so on.  Thus one needs a correction factor and that is what the equations do. Now if I replace the

```
data[i] = data[i];
data[i + 1] = data[i] * Math.Cos(phaseCorrection) + data[i+1] * Math.Sin(phaseCorrection);
```

with

```
data[i] = data[i];
data[i+1] = data[i+1];
```

it works ok.
So I'm going to need pointers.  But will this be substantially faster or will the sin and cosine functions just take too long?  Cn I send the data directly to the processor (now thats getting real unsafe!).

Comment: Does that `Read` method actually return an `IntPtr` or a pointer, because they are not the same thing?

Comment: Hi, Yes it is a IntPtr

Comment: @Tom see my updated answer on performance aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access unmanaged data directly in safe context, so you need to do a copy of data to managed container:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// ...

var data = new double[4096];
Marshal.Copy(pointer, data, 0, 4096);
// process data here
```

And as far as I see it, `unsafe` context is not required for this part of code.

As for the writing data back it's actually quite the same, but note the parameters order:

```
// finished processing, copying data back
Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pointer, 4096);
```

As for your last notes on perfprmance. As I already mentioned, move `var data = new double[8192];` to a `data` class member and initialize it in class constructor, so it's not allocated each time (and allocation is pretty slow). You can do `Math.Cos(phaseCorrection)` outside of cycle since `phaseCorrection` is unchanged, same is for `Math.Sin(phaseCorrection)` of course. Something like this:

```
Marshal.Copy(pointer, this.data, 0, 8192);

var cosCache = Math.Cos(phaseCorrection);
var sinCache = Math.Sin(phaseCorrection);
for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i+=2)
{
    data[i] = data[i];
    data[i + 1] = data[i] * cosCache + data[i+1] * sinCache; 
}

Marshal.Copy(this.data, 0, pointer2, 8192);
```

All this should speed up things tremendously.

Comment: Hi, Ok that works to get the data but then how does one put it back in the original buffer?

Comment: "You can't access unmanaged data directly." That's not true at all. You can party on memory all you like in an `unsafe` context.

Comment: @JimMischel I agree. I made edit so it's clear that it's the limitation of safe context.

Comment: The point, though, is that the OP has already asked about how to do it in an `unsafe` context. So this answer isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @JimMischel I can't agree with that. OP nor asked for answer in `unsafe` context, nor he seems unhappy with my answer in comment. I would assume that OP currently seeks just *any* way to access and modify the data.

Comment: Using the Marshall. Copy works. So I can copy the buffer to a new buffer and then copy it back to the output buffer. However, if I do the calculations on what I  need it is too slow. Can I answer my question without just adding comments? Add new code and more explanations?

Comment: @Tom, well, I guess then @JimMischel answer is the way to go, with unsafe direct access to buffer there is no need to copy data to buffer and back. But before that, try using class-member `data` buffer, so it's not created every time, this way performance can be significantly improved.

Comment: @Tom you can both edit, and answer your own question. If you want add more info to question - use edit, if you feel that you found solution that is better than all answers then add answer.

Comment: @Peter- Works perfect!! I now have fixed a long standing issue with the IQ balance in my app. The biggest problem I had is the huge amount of math I needed to go through to come up with this simple equation.Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `IntPtr`, you can get a pointer from it. Using your example:

```
    unsafe
    {
     IntPtr pointer =  Args.InBuffer.Read(); 

     // create a pointer to a double
     double* pd = (double*)pointer.ToPointer();

     // Now you can access *pd
     double firstDouble = *pd;
     pd++;  // moves to the next double in the memory block
     double secondDouble = *pd;

     // etc.
     }
```

Now, if you want to put data back into the array, it's much the same:

```
double* pd = (double*)pointer.ToPointer();
*pd = 3.14;
++pd;
*pd = 42.424242;
```

You need to read and understand [Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx). Be very careful with this; you're programming without a safety net here.

Comment: thanks I now know how to do this.  As it turns out it is not needed. I'm safe!